# Unable to retrieve item with id

Tags: 2013, publishing, content-manager, database

We have this problem when we open some pages in Tridion and to publish them.

[image]

Does anyone know what might be the cause?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you check in Windows Event Log of Tridion and possible more descriptive error. From the Error above, it seems there is an issue with the content - possibly a value in the parameter schema attached to the template or metadata value attached to the page

Comment: We have already solved. The problem was due to an incompatibility with some VB templates.

Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was due to an incompatibility with some VB templates. We have already solved the problem.

Comment: Hi Can you please tell me , How you solved above problem 
I also facing same issue for VB template in 2013 SP 1 HR 1.

Comment: Probably you have to reinstall your CMS with parameter LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE